# Rails 3 CKEDITOR: Paperclip Command Not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, ckeditor

When using CKEditor + Paperclip on rails 3 I get this error message when uploading an image via the wysiwyg editor:

Started POST "/ckeditor/pictures?CKEditor=question%5Banswers_attributes%5D%5B0%5D_body_editor&CKEditorFuncNum=2&langCode=en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-11 18:11:58 -0500
  Processing by Ckeditor::PicturesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"upload"=>#>, "CKEditor"=>"question[answers_attributes][0]_body_editor", "CKEditorFuncNum"=>"2", "langCode"=>"en"}
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/11/114evplqEWuTFgn6byOUQE+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20110611-1900-1hpvz8i.gif[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/11/114evplqEWuTFgn6byOUQE+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20110611-1900-1hpvz8i.gif[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY last_name ASC LIMIT 1
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 214ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)

Is this a error with paperclip or?

Comment: Is `identify` installed (image magick) and in the PATH for your application?

Comment: That seemed to work. Thanks so much Cameron!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is identify installed (image magick) and in the PATH for your application?

(posting so question doesn't appear in unanswered list)

Edit: Forgot to mention this might need to go in environments/*.rb:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin" # or path to wherever identify is located.
```